# IndexPath for first element in CollectionView

Tags: ios

How should look IndexPath for first position in CollectionView? I need to move certain element to first position:

```
collectionView.moveItem(at: collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!,
                                        to: *????*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IndexPath(item: Int, section: Int)`. In this case it will be

```
IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
```

You can even define a `zero` static variable as `CGRect` and other are doing

```
extension IndexPath {
    static let zero = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
}
```

and use it as

```
collectionView.moveItem(at: collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!, to: .zero))
```

Comment: This approach gives me following error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to move index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x60800002e980> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) that does not exist - there are only 0 items in section 0 before the update'

And i'm 100% sured, that moving called after collection populated with actual data.

Comment: `there are only 0 items in section 0 before the update` it says that the collectionView has no elements before the updates.

Comment: Double checked - collectionView has 5 elements by the time when moving method is called